# logout another user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use symfony 2 with FOSuserbundle. Creat action for lock user with code:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainUserBundle:User')
$user = $repository->findOneByUsername($request->request->get('name'));

/* some code */

$user->setLocked(true);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

But user get lock-in error message only if he logout and login again.
How i can logout another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455337/symfony-2-userinterfaceequalsuser-comparing-for-re-authentication/8456607#8456607) to a related question. Basically, you need to check for the lock flag in the `equals` method. This way, whenever the flag is changed, the user will have to reauthenticate.